# Postgres dump db

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin

Some months ago I used a postgres in 9.5 version. I crated a database backup (by using pgadmin) and restored this backup in postgres 9.6 (by using pgadmin as well). Database works fine but there is a problem to create a backup from postgres 9.6 (currently there are much more data than a few months ago).

I tried to do it by using pgadmin but there is an error:

`pg_dump: server version: 9.6.16; pg_dump version: 9.5.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch`

Then I tried to create backup from command line by using:

`pg_dump dbname > dbname-backup.dump`

or

`pg_dump dbname > dbname-backup.sql`

but if I executed this scripts - nothing happend. There is no error, no any message, backup is no generated.

There is a windows 10 and pgadmin 3. 
How is it possible to crate a backup of this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgAdmin 3 only supports up to Postgres 9.5 and is itself no longer supported. You should [upgrade to pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/).